# Min and max of matrix in python without numpy

Tags: python, matrix, position, max, min

I have a problem. How to find max and min of matrix in Python without using numpy, just old and slow way. I need to display their positions as well.

Comment: With matrix do you mean a list of lists?

Comment: Please share some of your code for us to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2D numerical lists, a method for what you want, is list comprehension:

```
mat=[[3,1.5,4,2],[5,9,3,8]]

_min_=min([(min(element),mat.index(element),element.index(min(element))) for element in mat])

print(_min_) # prints (1.5,0,1)
```

where the first to third elements in the output represent the minimum, the index of row of *mat* to which that minimum belongs and the index of column of *mat* to which that minimum belongs.

You can generalize this method for any n-dimensional list if you wish.